# What happens when I am initializing my UIView in subclasses?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, initializing

**A.swift**

```
class A: UIView {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        println("init A")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        println("initFrame A")
    }
}
```

**B.swift**

```
class B: A {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        //P1
        println("init B")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        println("initFrame B")
    }
}
```

Then I call it `B()`:

I have an output:

```
initFrame A
initFrame B
init A
init B
```

I try to determine **what?** is called and **when?**... after `B()`. I wish to understand it completely.

1. `init()` in `A`
2. `super.init()` in `init()` in `A`
3. `init()` in `B`
4. `super.init()` in `init()` in `B`
5. `init()` in `UIView`
6. `super.init()` in `init()` in `UIView`

now we are in `P1` point, right?

7. `init()` calls `init(frame:)` in `B` with `CGRectZero`
8. `super.init(frame:)` in `init(frame:)` in `B`
9. `init(frame:)` in `A`
10. `super.init(frame:)` in `init(frame:)` in `A`
11. `init(frame:)` in `UIView`
12. `super.init(frame:)` in `init(frame:)` in `UIView`

now we are getting back

13. called the rest of `init(frame:)` in `UIView`
14. called the rest of `init(frame:)` in `A` --> **initFrame A**
15. called the rest of `init(frame:)` in `B` --> **initFrame B**

The question is what is happening now? Where we are now? (inside `init()` in `UIView`?) Where are printed the lines with `init A` and `init B`?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `B()` calls `B`'s `init()`
2. This results in a call to `init()` defined in `B`'s superclass `A` (due to `super.init()` in `B`'s `init()`)
3. This, in turn, results in a call to `init()` defined in `A`'s superclass `UIView` (due to `super.init()` in `A`'s `init()`)
4. `UIView`'s `init()` invokes `init(frame: CGRectZero)` on the current instance
5. Since the current instance is of class `B`, and class `B` overrides `init(frame: CGRect)`, `B`'s own implementation of the method is invoked
6. This results in a call to `A`'s `init(frame: CGRectZero)` (due to `super.init(frame: frame)` in `B`'s `init(frame: CGRect)`)
7. As a consequence, `UIView`'s `init(frame: CGRectZero)` is called (due to `super.init(frame: frame)` in `A`'s own implementation)
8. This concludes the chain of calls
9. Great, now we're going back down to `A`'s `init(frame: CGRectZero)` (point 6 in the list), which prints `initFrame A`
10. Back down to `B`'s `init(frame: CGRectZero)` (point 5), which prints `initFrame B`
11. Now back again to `UIView`'s `init()` (point 3), which doesn't print anything
12. We return to `A`'s `init()` (point 2), that prints `initA`
13. Finally, we finish our trip at `B`'s `init()` (point 1), which prints `initB`, that you marked with `P1`

Please let me know if the steps are clear, of if I need to add more details to improve the explanation: I know it's a bit convoluted.